# Integrate MS Dynamics AX with Play Framework

Tags: sql-server, playframework, rabbitmq, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

In my company we use MS Dynamics AX 2009. We have around 100 users.
The servers of MS Dynamics AX are in the headquarters company.

We are developping a new website using Play Framework and Scala language. However, the website server isn't in the headquarters company, the dedicated server is hosted in OVH, an European ISP.

The website needs the ERP data in real time, but the MS Dynamics AX Database is located in the headquarters company and the internet connection is very unstable.

That's the problem! We need bidirectional comunication between the website and the ERP, but the internet connection of the ERP Servers are very unstable.
We've thought two solutions:

- Use RabbitMQ in the headquarters and website. When an event occurs in the ERP, the ERP puts a message in RabbitMQ and the website gets this message when the internet connection works. When an event occurs in the website, the website puts a message in RabbitMQ and the ERP gets this message when the internet connections works. So, we have 2 RabbitMQ, one in the headquarters and another one in the website server.
- Use MS SQL Server Replication to replicate the database from headquarters to ISP, we would need two servers in the ISP: the website (Linux, Apache, MySQL, Play Framework) and the SQL Replica (Windows, SQL Server). When an event occurs in ERP, the SQL Server replication propagate these changes to the SQL Replication server in the ISP, and the website always reads the data in the SQL Replication Server. When an event occurs in website, we also need a RabbitMQ queue like before.

What do you think about this architecture? What is the best solution? Could MS SQL Server replicate ussing an unstable internet conecction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software architecture and design and so it's a better fit at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Stack Overflow is [a question-and-answer resource, not a discussion forum](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/92115/228805). It's for specific questions about coding that can have definite answers. You might try [programmers.se], which is for discussions of high-level design concepts and best practices. Please read [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/82990/228805) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know it.

Comment: I've just copied the question to Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/250852/integrate-ms-dynamics-ax-with-play-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked for a company in Mexico that had an unstable internet connection and had to develop a custom solution with a 3rd party product.

One comment/thought is that do you really need **ALL** your ERP data or just a smaller subset?

I'm not entirely sure what RabbitMQ is, but if it's like MSMQ then it doesn't sound like a bad idea.

I'd suggest using the AIF and MSMQ (actually uses WCF & *NetMsmq* binding) or getting a third party product like Scribe/CastIron/Biztalk to help.  The third party product would most likely be your best bet.

MSMQ I'd think would work because it sends everything to message queues to send/receive, and works asynchronously.  DB mirroring is a pain, especially with a spotty internet connection.  You'll probably end up with most of the mirroring happening at night, and losing your real-time data.

Comment: Thank you very much. RabbitMQ is a queue engine like MSMQ.
You said "DB mirroring is a pain, especially with a spotty internet connection", so, I think it's better the first solution with queues.

Comment: Sure thing.  The biggest thing, I think, is identifying the subset of data you really need.